# Delete Closing Tags with line in notepad++ (HTML)

Tags: tags, notepad++

If in notepad++ I want to delete a line which has a < div> tag on it, is there a way to automatically delete the closing line containing < /div> without deleting the lines inbetween?

So in this example to delete lines 1 and 18 whilst retaining lines 2 to 17

image of code at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I3fy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a little bit convoluted bit it can be done purely in notepad++

1. Make sure you have the HTML Tag plugin installed. This can be done by going into Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager, selecting the plugin named HTML Tag and installing it (if you haven't already). Or install it manually by downloading it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/HTMLTag/HTMLTag%20plugin%20v0.50/HTMLTag_plugin_v0.5.0_src.zip/download)
2. Have your text cursor over the start or end tag of the tags you want to remove and press CTRL+SHIFT+T. This will select the entire element and all of its children
3. Press CTRL+H to bring up the find and replace window.
   ->Select Regular expression mode,
   ->make sure 'In Selection' is checked,
   ->use the expression `(?s)\A<[^>]*>(.*?)<[^>]*>\Z` in the 'find what' text box
   ->and the replacement `\1` in the 'replace with' text box.
4. Now press the replace all button to remove the first and last tag.

Repeat steps 2 to 4 for any other replacements of this kind.

Using this method the example:

```
<div class="col-md-4 sidebar">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            News Feed
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Past Posts
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">News feed</p>
    <ul>
        <li>post 5</li>
        <li>post 4</li>
        <li>post 3</li>
        <li>post 2</li>
        <li>post 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            News Feed
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Past Posts
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">News feed</p>
    <ul>
        <li>post 5</li>
        <li>post 4</li>
        <li>post 3</li>
        <li>post 2</li>
        <li>post 1</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I know of will do this in notepad++.

You can't select multiple ranges of text, only a single continuous block of text. Unfortunately to delete text you have to select it and as there is no multiple range selection there is no way to perform the desired deletion.

There are plugins that can find the matching tag and changing language to HTML will also highlight the matching tag. This will let you easily see the location of the matching tag, but you will still have to select and delete the matching tag manually.